# remove seasonality from weekly time series data

Tags: r, time-series

I need to decompose a series to remove seasonality. The series has 2 columns date and volume.

This is what my time series object looks like:

```
salestsDec <- ts(salests, frequency=52, start=c(2010, 1), end=c(2014,12))
```

I ran the `decompose()` function on a 'ts' object.

```
salests = sales[, c(1,6)]
View(salests)
salestsDec <- ts(salests, frequency=52, start=c(2010, 1), end=c(2014,12))
salestsDec <- decompose(salestsDec, type=c("additive"))
plot(salestsDec)
```

Upon, running the `decompose()` function, I get a list of 6 components, observed, trend, seasonal, random for both date and volume. I should only be seeing, observed, trend, seasonal and random component for Volume in my plot.

I've attached an image of what the plot looks like.

Moreover, when I try to remove seasonal component from the series, I am getting an error. It appears that it's the same underlying issue.

Error:

Error in salests - salestsDec$seasonal : non-numeric argument to binary operator In addition: Warning message: Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.ts") for "-"

[image: Time series components plot after running decomposed()]

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate (without having the data), but from what I see, you are trying to apply the *decompose* function to the entire object - it's probably expecting a single vector, but receives a data-frame-like object and attempts to apply the decomposition to both columns. either use a different time series package (like zoo) which does not store timestamps as a column, or apply decompose explicitly to salestsDec[,2].

Comment: Thanks @kpb. That worked like a charm. However, my plot looks fine now with observed, trend, seasonal and random component. I get a error when I try to subtract seasonal component from the decomposed series. It appears that I can perform a math operation on the series as it is not numeric and needs conversion.                                                                                 Error looks like this: `code` Error in `-.default`(salestsDec, salestsDec$seasonal) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator `code`.

Comment: @keval: again, tricky without replication, but if  I understand correctly you are trying to subtract the seasonality from the original series. If that is the case, either add the remaining components (trend + random) or subtract salestsDec$seasonal from salestsDec[,2] and not from salestsDec. Better still, can you post the output of str(salestsDec, max.level = 1) or somesuch? That should have info on object classes, dimensions etc.